# Unable to open service externally on Rancher

Tags: spring, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, rancher

#### Issue with rancher opening external port

- Installed rancher 2.6 ,
- deployed a springboot app with 8080 port open docker image
- Set internal port as 8080, external(nodeport) as 31000 and port on image container as 8080
- Trying to access :31000 , getting 404 please help

**i'm stuck here!!! Need help**

[image]

**I tried changing the node port, disabling the firewall and restarting machine**

Answer (score 0):

The Fact you are getting a 404 is that something is answering your request.

I would do the following to try to troubleshoot.

1. Use port-forward to check your app is running on the cluster fine:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/movies-db-np 8080
```

Check it on http://localhost:8080

2. Verify the service has the correct selector for your pod/deployment e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 31000
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: my.docker/myapp:1.0.0
        name: myapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
...
```

Note here, the service will match pods with label `app=myapp`.